# VBA code: User is not a member of HelloWorld.My

Tags: vb.net

I'm not new to programming, but am new to Microsoft-centric technologies. In this case, I have downloaded Visual Studio 2019 Community edition and am trying to get some stuff working as a VBA Console application.

Here is the link the the Visual Basic Guide I am using as documentation:
https://opdhsblobprod02.blob.core.windows.net/contents/c6aea4f5457448ee818b7292ba695982/8f8c9552565899a6bd5ea3443dc48752?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=z6HVPKMrsWrYMl1xp9Pk34R040%2B8A71q3nmRLNTG6lk%3D&st=2019-10-18T21%3A16%3A48Z&se=2019-10-19T21%3A26%3A48Z&sp=r

On Page #1 of that guide is a section titled "Development with My". 'My' can have various pieces, depending on the project type. In this case, my project type is: Console Application (from VS, File -> New -> Project, select: Console App (.NET Core) )

On page 59 of that guide is a table that explicitly shows which different parts of 'My' would be available in different project types. For a Console App, all of My.User, My.Resources, My.Setting should be available (as well as some other things).

Yet within my VBA code, the editor implies that the only part of 'My' available is a My.InternalXmlHelper. (I guess that comes by default - I haven't done anything to explicitly try to add such a thing.)

Obviously, some piece of the puzzle is missing here that enables access to all this wonder 'My' functionality that is described. Anybody know what needs to be done here so that my VS environment knows about My.User (and other stuff)?

Thanks.

Comment: Please note that VBA and Basic and VB.NET are three different languages. What you started is a VB.NET project (which is the same thing your guide uses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Core is a different beast altogether, in addition to the other languages you seem to be mixing together.

Based on [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-in-net-core-3-0/) link, VB `My` namespace support is not a part of core 3.0. I'm not sure if it's in earlier core versions, because I haven't been working with VB in Core.

> A large part of what makes Visual Basic special is the Visual Basic Runtime. .NET Core 2 contains only the small part of Visual Basic Runtime that is defined in the Visual Basic Language Specification which was initially designed for interop with phones.
>
> The major effort for Visual Basic 16.0 will be moving the Visual Basic Runtime to .NET Core 3.0 to provide expected features like Mid or the My namespace. This work will probably not be ready for the first preview of .NET Core 3.0 but will appear in a later preview.

I think the guide you are working with is for .NET Framework 4.x and earlier (Core is a different initiative that involves getting .NET to run on multiple Operating Systems, etc.). Try creating a new .NET Framework app. The templates will have `(.NET Framework)` in the name, e.g., `ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)`.